# Sharing an already shared location using NFS

Tags: filesystems, mount, nfs, file-sharing

Is it possible to share a shared location with another system using NFS ?

For Eg:

Shared location is auto-mounted and appears in **/etc/fstab** of machine2 :

```
machine1:/loc1  /shared_location  nfs defaults
```

I want to share the folder /shared_location from machine2 to  machine3 using nfs.

I edited **/etc/exports** to add the line :

```
/shared_location  machine2(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

When i try to execute the mount command (in machine3 ) :

```
mount -t nfs machine2:/shared_location  /new_shared_location
```

I get the error :

> mount: machine2:/shared_location   /new_shared_location  failed,
>   reason given by server: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

seems old question... still answering.

try to run "sudo exportfs -v -a" on server.